# Question about true using of abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, matrix, abstract-class

I'm writing program to work with different types of matrices such sparse matrices and other.
Now I have complete class of one matrix type called DOK and decided that I need an abstract class Matrix to be inherited in other child matrices and I will be able to apply all virtual operations
with different classes. So I made
**Base class**:

```
#include "Triplet.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class Matrix{
public:
    virtual Matrix<T>& operator*=(const Matrix<T>& B) = 0;

    virtual const Matrix<T>& operator*(const Matrix<T>& B) const = 0;

    virtual Matrix<T>& operator-=(const Matrix<T>& B) = 0;

    virtual const Matrix<T>& operator-(const Matrix<T>& B) const = 0;

    virtual Matrix<T>& operator+=(const Matrix<T>& B) = 0;

    virtual const Matrix<T>& operator+(const Matrix<T>& B) const = 0;

    virtual T operator()(int i, int j) = 0;

    virtual T operator()(int i, int j) const = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual int getSizeN() const = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual int getSizeM() const = 0;

    [[maybe_unused]] virtual void insert(const Triplet<T> &Element) = 0;
    [[maybe_unused]] virtual void print() const = 0;
};
template<typename  T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Matrix<T>& matrix) {
    matrix.print();
    return os;
}
```

**Triplet.h** is struct

```
template<typename T>
struct Triplet{
    int i;
    int j;
    T b;
};
```

Tabs is

```
template<typename T>
T Tabs(T num){
    if(num<T(0)) return -num;
    else return num;
}
```

And child **class DOK**:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include "Triplet.h"
//#include "Solver.h"
#include "Tabs.h"
#include "cmath"
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
T tolerance = T(1e-19);

template<typename T>
class DOK: public Matrix<T>{
private:
    /*
     * Dictionary of Keys, pair<int, int> is coordinates of non-zero elements,
     * next int is value
     */

    int size_n;
    int size_m;
    map<pair<int, int>, T> dict;
    // int count;
public:

    DOK(vector<Triplet<T>> &matrix, int n, int m){
        this->resize(n, m);
        this->fill(matrix);
    }

    DOK(int n, int m){
        this->resize(n, m);
    }
    ~DOK() = default;

    void fill(vector<Triplet<T>> &matrix){
        //this->count=matrix.size();
        //cout<<"Input your coordinates with value in format \"i j val\" "<<endl;
        for(int k = 0; k < matrix.size(); k++){
            this->insert(matrix[k]);
        }
    }

    void insert(const Triplet<T> &Element) override{
        if(Element.i >= this->size_n){
            this->size_n = Element.i+1;
        }
        if(Element.j >= this->size_m){
            this->size_m = Element.j+1;
        }
        pair<int, int> coordinates = {Element.i, Element.j};
        this->dict.insert(pair(coordinates, Element.b));
    }

    void resize(int n, int m){
        this->size_n=n;
        this->size_m=m;
    }
    void print() const override {
        cout<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < this->size_n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < this->size_m; j++){
                if(this->dict.find({i, j})!= this->dict.cend()) cout<< fixed << setprecision(18)<<this->dict.find(pair(i, j))->second<<" "; else cout<<0<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

    void clearZeros(){
        for(auto i = this->dict.begin(); i!=this->dict.end();){
            if(Tabs(i->second) <=  tolerance<T>){
                i = this->dict.erase(i);
            } else{
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    [[nodiscard]] int getSizeN() const override{
        return this->size_n;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] int getSizeM() const override{
        return this->size_m;
    }
    void clearZeros(){
        for(auto i = this->dict.begin(); i!=this->dict.end();){
            if(Tabs(i->second) <=  tolerance<T>){
                i = this->dict.erase(i);
            } else{
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    DOK<T>& operator+=(const Matrix<T> &matrix) override {
        try{
            if(this->getSizeN() != matrix.getSizeN() || this->getSizeM() != matrix.getSizeM()) throw 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < this->getSizeN(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this->getSizeM(); j++) {
                    T c = this->operator()(i, j) + matrix(i, j);
                    if(Tabs(c) > tolerance<T>) this->insert({i, j, c}); else this->dict.erase({i, j});
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }
        catch (int a) {
            cout<<"Sizes of Matrices are different."<<endl;
        }
    }

    const DOK<T>& operator+(const Matrix<T>& matrix) const override {
        DOK<T> t = *this;
        return move(t+=matrix);
    }

    DOK<T>& operator-=(const Matrix<T>& matrix) override {
        try{
            if(this->getSizeN() != matrix.getSizeN() || this->getSizeM() != matrix.getSizeM()) throw 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < this->getSizeN(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this->getSizeM(); j++) {
                    T c = this->operator()(i, j) - matrix(i, j);
                    if(Tabs(c) > tolerance<T>) this->insert({i, j, c}); else this->dict.erase({i, j});
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }
        catch (int a) {
            cout<<"Sizes of Matrices are different."<<endl;
        }
    }

    const DOK<T>& operator-(const Matrix<T> &matrix) const override {
        DOK<T> t = *this;
        return move(t-=matrix);
    }

    DOK<T>& operator*=(const Matrix<T> &matrix) override {
        try {
            if(this->getSizeN() != matrix.getSizeN()) throw 1;
            DOK<T> M = DOK(this->getSizeN(), matrix.getSizeM());
            for (int i = 0; i < this->getSizeN(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.getSizeM(); j++) {
                    T a=0;
                    for(int k = 0; k<this->getSizeM(); k++){
                        if(this->operator()(i, k) != 0 && matrix(k, j) != 0){
                            a+=this->operator()(i, k)*matrix(k,j);
                            //cout<<a<<endl;
                        }
                    }
                    Triplet<T> m = {i, j, a};
                    M.insert(m);
                }
            }
            this->clearZeros();
            *this=M;
            return *this;
        }
        catch (int a) {
            cout<<"Wrong sizes of matrices to multiplication"<<endl;
        }
    }

    const DOK<T>& operator*(const Matrix<T>& matrix) const override{
        DOK<T> t = *this;
        return t*=matrix;
    }
    T operator()(int row, int col) override{
        if(this->dict.find({row, col}) != dict.end()) return this->dict.find({row, col})->second;
        else return T(0);
    }

    T operator()(int row, int col) const override{
        if(this->dict.find({row, col}) != dict.end()) return this->dict.find({row, col})->second;
        else return T(0);
    }
};
```

But I faced a problem that now I can't create DOK object because Matrix is an abstract class.
So if I did

```
DOK<double> Q = DOK<double>(...)
cout<<Q*Q;
```

and it was working
but now I can't do like this and one possible variant is to dereference pointer

```
Matrix<double>* Q = new DOK<double>(...);
cout<<(*Q) * (*Q);
```

How can I fix it without rewriting code from references to pointers?

Comment: Your `operator*` returns a reference to a local object. It should return object by value.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what it is that is not working? Both examples you gave (`DOK<double> Q = ...` and `Matrix<double>* Q = ...`) work fine.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yes first example works but since I have Base class I want to create matrices by
```Matrix<double> *Q = new DOK<double>(...)``` and use all operators. But when I want to apply any operator it expect reference so Q*=Q will not work because Q is a pointer

Comment: Ah ok. The only option I see is creating a reference: `Matrix<double> *Q = ...; Matrix<double> &R = *Q; std::cout << R * R;` But that is not what you want either?

Comment: @G.Sliepen ohhh ok, I will keep it in mind but is there any other solutions or the rightest way is to rewrite everything to pointers?

Comment: If you want to overload `operator*` for pointers, then this is impossible, because you can only overload it if at least one of the arguments is a user-defined type.

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: How about take operator+,  operator-, operator* out of class? Define these operators as friend functions which taking two arguments. And you may overload each operator with all different pairs of arguments, and return a type of your design.  e.g  operator*(const matrix<T>, const matrix<T>), and operator*(const matrix<T>, const DOK<T>), operator*(const DOK<T>, const DOK<T>), even mixed type product operator*(const matrix<T1>, const matrix<T2>) if you can somehow determine the return type.

Comment: @ytlu How can I reload it with argument Matrix<T> If it is an abstract class that can't be an object and later I will have at least 5 classes, so I need to make minimum  32 overloads only for one operator?

Comment: @Dmitri Petrov Using double template for 5 classes to cover most of the 32 combinations. But the return type is rather troublesome. Therefore you might have to write some explicit template sepcilazation. Personal bias, I don't like to write binary function as a member function.

Comment: @Dmitri Petrov my heartly advice is that your matrix class structure is far too complicate, probaly less efficiency. If I were you, I will redesign the whole structure. You might spent very much time, and get little pay-off.

Comment: @Dmitri Petrov The critical factor for matrix manipulation perfomance is the speed of elemnt access. Therefore the core of matrix ( 2d array ) has to keep fixed after allocation. All utilities is written on top of this core. For exmple, copy matrix a to matrix b, you will use memory copy instead of element to element assign. Therefore, you have to be very clear about the memory is compact and  safely accessible.

Comment: Yeah but I want to understand how to use Base class with methods made by references. I looked at Eigen library and it seems to be something like mine(Base class and ChildClasses with methods working by references, but we dont need to take reverence from created pointer to an object to work with it. But it is difficult to me to understand whole code in Eigen)